# Setting JSON array in state, does not show propper javascript object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm experimenting with fetch APIs in react, where I'm getting some dummy data, from a server I created myself.

Inside my componentDidMount lifecycle hook, I met a fetch call to the server.

```
componentDidMount(){
  axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/data/50/1')
  .then(res =>{
    console.log(res.data)
    this.setState({
      names: res.data
    }, ()=>{
      console.log(this.state.names)
    })

  })
console.log(this.state.names)
}
```

so in here, whenever I pass a callback into my setState I properly log an array of json objects, which is desired.

However in my render method:

```
render() {
console.log("state is" + this.state.names)
```

it logs nothing on the first render (i guess this is because of setState works asynchronous, but the second time it simply logs

```
state is[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],`[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`
```

why is not displaying a proper array when I log the state, in the render method, but it's showing correctly when I pass a callback into my setState method

[image: Logged console]

Comment: What is the output of the first console.log in your code?

Comment: I added an image of the log in displayed order i added a string in front of it, to see where it was logged

Comment: I meant the first console.log - the `res.data` that you actually got back from the API.

Comment: apologies, it displays the array like it should, i also tried making a button with a onClick handler, which also displayed the array just fine

Comment: Just do `console.log("state is", this.state.names)` instead. "It is not displaying properly" ... why? It works as expected?

Comment: Where are you refering to @JonasWilms

Comment: What does `console.log(this.state.names[0])` show? It's possible the data is there as expected, but the console.log is concatenating the output.

Comment: @Toby this just shows a simply Object object

Comment: My initial though was to display the data in a table, which also works, I'm just wondering how it can recognize the objects, but not the fact, that It's javascript objects

Comment: Maybe try `res.data.json()`, or `JSON.stringify(res.data)` ? It's difficult to troubleshoot without being able to run the code.

Comment: This is the exact output I would expect from an array of objects being coerced to a string with the `+` operator.

Comment: The request is asynchronous so you need a conditional in `render()` to account for that data not being there at the beginning. `render()` will not wait for that request

Comment: But why does it not display an actual array of javascript arguments, but simple the object object text

Comment: That's because `String + Array` casts the array to string and `[object Object]` is the string representation of an object

Comment: Arrrgh i understand it know, you can post as answer and i will accept, for other people, might have the same confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be:

```
console.log("State is: ", this.state.names)
```

instead of

```
console.log("State is: " + this.state.names)
```